# I am unable to convert this JS Function to C#. Can't find isNan and || to replace

Tags: javascript, c#, formatting, currency, currency-formatting

Js code is:

```
var thousand = ',';
var decimal = '.';
var decimalPlaces = 2;

function formatMoney(number, places, symbol, thousand, decimal, Alignment) {
    symbol = '$';
    number = number || 0;
    places = !isNaN(places = Math.abs(places)) ? places : 2;
    symbol = symbol !== undefined ? symbol : "$";
    if (typeof thousand == 'undefined' || thousand == null) {
        thousand = ",";
    }

    decimal = decimal || ".";
    var negative = number < 0 ? "-" : "",
        i = parseInt(number = Math.abs(+number || 0).toFixed(places), 10) + "",
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    if (typeof Alignment != 'undefined' && Alignment != null && Alignment.toLowerCase() == "right") {

        return negative + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thousand : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thousand) + (places ? decimal + Math.abs(number - i).toFixed(places).slice(2) : "") + symbol;
    }
    else {
        return symbol + negative + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thousand : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thousand) + (places ? decimal + Math.abs(number - i).toFixed(places).slice(2) : "");
    }
}
```

So i want this code in C#
I have tried using Parse as a replacement for isNan but i am unable to do for ||

Comment: Could you please share C# code you have attempted ?

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=c%23+isnan+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: `||` exists in `C#`. What exactly is your problem with `||`?

Comment: number = number || 0;

How can i convert this?

Comment: @NikhilChaudhary `||` stands for `OR`, which means both operands should be `bool` (in `C#`).

Comment: Also you might want to consider avoiding naming variables `decimal` (which is a type)

Comment: In JS: number = number || 0;

in C# i've tried

 public void TestFunction()
        {
            int n = 123456789;
            n = n || false;
        }

Comment: @Ivar I'm not very familiar with javascript, but is `+number` really valid on its own?

Comment: @Rafalon It's an easy way to convert a [string to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133814). (And if the variable already is a number, it remains as is.)

Comment: @Ivar thanks, I didn't know that :) so it converts the value to a number, then gets its absolute value, and parses it to `int` to put it back to a string O.O this seems quite over-complicating stuff to me (and if the original string wasn't a number, it gets 0)

Comment: places = !isNaN(places = Math.abs(places)) ? places : 2;

How can i convert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `number` is a nullable (e.g. `decimal?`) in your C# code, you can use the [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operator as replacement for `||`:

```
number = number ?? 0;
```

Since C# is a strongly typed language, you won't have to worry about any arbitrary types being passed like in JS. You can declare the `places` parameter as `int?` and then simply do:

```
places = places.HasValue ? Math.Abs(places.Value) : 2;
```

You should also mind, that there are already a lot of built-in functions for [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) and [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) formatting in C#, including a specific [currency format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-currency-c-format-specifier), so you might want to have a look at that.

**Example:**

```
static string FormatMoney(decimal number, int places, string symbol, string thousand, string @decimal, int alignment)
{  
    var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
    nfi.CurrencyGroupSeparator = thousand;
    nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = @decimal;
    nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = places;
    nfi.CurrencySymbol = symbol;
    nfi.CurrencyPositivePattern = alignment;
    return number.ToString("C", nfi);
}

decimal value = 123456.789m;
Console.WriteLine(FormatMoney(value, 2, "$", ",", ".", 0));

// OUTPUT:
// $123,456.79
```

Comment: These are the types

int? number, string places,string  symbol,string  thousand,string  decimal,string  Alignment

Comment: @NikhilChaudhary It depends on how you want to use the function. Please also have a look at the built-in formatting functions I've included in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i need the converstion with help of number format like: '1.234.567,89' , '1,234,567.89', '1.234.567', etc means whatever i define in the format, it should convert like that

Comment: @NikhilChaudhary Yes that's what the formatting functions are for.

Comment: @NikhilChaudhary See my edit. That's basically exactly what you need, all with built-in functionality. Maybe not perfect yet, but will get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i am having problem when we use Console.WriteLine(FormatMoney(value, 2, "$", ".", ",", 0));     It should give $123.456,79

Comment: Ok i changed NumberGroupSeparator to nfi.CurrencyGroupSeparator = thousand;

Working fine for me now thanks

Comment: @NikhilChaudhary Yea sorry, my mistake. I pieced together this function in a very short time. Also have a look at CurrencyNegativePattern and the respective values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about undefined as if it is your function's parameter, it is always defined otherwise compiler gives an error before running it. Javascript is different as you can define a parameter without passing anything to function.
you have to say for example

```
 public string formatMoney(int number, string places,string  symbol,string  thousand,string  decimal,string  Alignment)
```

so thousand is always defined

You just need to replace :

```
if (typeof thousand == 'undefined' || thousand == null)
```

with

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(thousand))
```

if thousand is string

Comment: and what about this?
places = !isNaN(places = Math.abs(places)) ? places : 2;

Answer (score 0):

The || operator isn't available in C# for setting variables (I guess that's where it needs replacement). So for that you can just check the value (e.g. `number = (number == null) ? 0 : number;`).

For the isNaN you could create a function like:

```
public bool IsNumeric(string value)
{
     return value.All(char.IsNumber);
}
```

and use this to check if something is a number or not.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `number = (number == null) ? 0 : number;` could simply be written `number = number ?? 0;`

Comment: @Rafalon How did I not know about this: `number = number ?? 0;` :p

Comment: In the JS code, `places` _is_ a number, so you might want to use `double.IsNaN(places)`